# How do I end my str.findall() on a specific point?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

Column in question

[image]

Hello everyone,
Learning about regex and trying to tackle this problem here. Basically I'm looking to separate the two addresses so that I can add them into a dataframe as separate addresses.

```
for column in maindf_clean:
    address1=maindf_clean['Line 1: address Line 2: address2'].str.findall('(?<=:).*')
    print(address1)
    print('-----')
```

Outputs:`[ 3461 Bartillon Lane Line 2: Suite 26]`

So I've managed to remove 'Line 1:' however, I am unsure of how to get it to stop the match after, in this example, the word lane.

I've managed to extract the second address using this code:

```
for column in maindf_clean:
    address2=maindf_clean['Line 1: address Line 2: address2'].str.findall('^.+:(.+)$')
    print(address2)
    print('-----')
```

Outputs: `[ Suite 26]`

So my question is, is there a way to edit my str.findall in the first for loop to end between the end of the first address and the word 'Line 2:'?

Comment: Do `Line 1` and `Line 2` really appear on the _same_ line?

Comment: I believe so! When I look at the csv/dataframe, for each row the two addresses for a given person are in that same column. So my understanding is that they would be on the same line when trying to match. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookahead so the match stops at the next `Line` or the end of the string. And use a non-greedy quantifier.

```
address1=maindf_clean['Line 1: address Line 2: address2'].str.findall(r'(?<=:).*?(?=\s+Line \d|\s+$)')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help! That seemed to do the trick. If you don't mind me asking (I'm still trying to figure it out) but could you explain exactly what the part you added in does? 
I was reading some sources on line and tried to implement \s earlier and was getting blanks in the output. Does that second group say to end where there is a space and the word 'Line'?

Comment: @IPadaJT You could try https://regex101.com/. This website will explain each regex symbol mean, also you can debug why the result is like that

Comment: Thank you, this looks perfect for me to tinker with!

Comment: @IPadaJT The lookahead participates in matching the pattern, but isn't included in the result. So it forces the match to stop before the next `Line`. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html